# How can I use Regex to capture a certain set of ages?

Tags: regex

I have a set of data, like below;

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,12
11,13,15
7,8,12
```

And so on...  I am trying to use Regex in to target a certain set of ages between 1-7, but I am getting matches on any double digit which contains any of these characters too.  My regex is currently as below;

```
/^(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)|(6)|(7)|$/g
```

My current matches include 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 - perfect.  However, it matches the line with 11,13,15 and 7,8,12 - not what I wanted.

Any advice would be appreciated on how to resolve?  Thanks in advance, I am continuing to try to correct.

Comment: `^(1)|(2) ...` only matches `1` at the beginning of the string, it does not match `1 OR 2` at the beginning of the string. I found that `^[1-7]$` does what you want by testing [here](https://regex101.com/), though I had to use the `m` option for "multi line mode", in addition to the `g` option that you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **word boundaries**:

```
\b[1-7]\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zO7lG3/1).

As pointed out by @Quantic, this matches numbers from 1-7 regardless where they are.
If you only want to have *lines* where there is a number between 1-7, you'll need to use anchors:

```
^[0-7]$
```

Or if you want to capture the number:

```
^([0-7])$
```

With this, you'll need the `multiline` flag, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zO7lG3/2) as well.

Comment: This matches the `7, 8, 12` line which OP doesn't want.

Comment: @Jan I would advocate for the original suggestion: It doesn't answer the OP's question as written, but it answers the logical question he asked: He said he didn't want to match the `7,8,12` line. he never said he didn't want to match the `7`. It's conjecture until he answers.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Also good point. Thinking about the semantics of his question it is ambiguous right now what he wants. But I assume he does want the `multiline` flag because his original regex matches only the `7` and the `2` on the end of that line, not the whole line, yet he says it "matches the line" which he doesn't want.

Comment: Thanks @Jan this did the job well - really appreciate it, and the additional comments from TemporalWolf and Quantic. Apologies for not being clear in the question. 

If I was to take this one step further, and say - match any line which contains a [1-7] but does not contain anything between 8-17, how would I do that?  i.e. so it would match a line with 2, 6 but not match a line with 2, 12?

Comment: @PhilBarnes: Just ask another question with your desired result :) This might be too unreadable for the comments section.

Answer (score 2):

`(?<!\d)[1-7](?!\d)`

This looks for any digit 1-7 that does not have another digit on either side of it. (using negative lookbehind/lookahead)

[regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/jJ5xX6/1)

Comment: I like this one (+1), however not every engine (ie `JavaScript`) supports lookbehinds.